# Linux NVME SSD support

Tags: nvme

I have Ideapad 530s laptop. Ubuntu 18.04.2, 18.10 and 19.04 install images don't seem to detect the drive at all. The drive, however, is successfully detected by Windows 10.

Windows 10 shows that the nvme drive model is RPFTJ128PDD2EWX. Is there a way I can get the drive to work in Ubuntu?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, I have disabled the windows fast boot. On live CD lspci command does not even show the nvme device.

Comment: I found a solution. I Replaced laptop's nvme drive with Samsung Evo nvme drive and now the system works just fine. Probably there are nvme drives that are not supported by Linux.

Comment: The non-working nvme SSD is labeled as "Union Memory". It would be good to know if driver for it is coming to Linux.